# manual backup of files task runs successfully but nothing was done

Tags: windows

I scheduled a task running this cmd of backup on a Windows Server 2012. It used to work without the forfiles which is supposed to keep the folder/files of only 6 days' entries.

```
SET date_stamp=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~4,2%

forfiles /p E:\Test_Backups\ /D -6 /C "cmd /c del /s /q @PATH"
for /f "usebackq" %d in (`dir /ad/b/s "E:\Test_Backups\"`) do rd "%d"
forfiles /p E:\Test2_Backups\ /D -6 /C "cmd /c del /s /q @PATH"
for /f "usebackq" %d in (`dir /ad/b/s "E:\Test2_Backups\"`) do rd "%d"

mkdir "E:\Test_Backups\%date_stamp%"
mkdir "E:\Test2_Backups\%date_stamp%"

::stop some services
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -m0=COPY "E:\Test_Backups\%date_stamp%\%date_stamp%-TestApp.7z" "D:\Test"
::start some services
```

And now, it stopped working. The task scheduler's history says it ran, but nothing was backup-ed in "E:\Test_Backups\". Even mkdir did not run.

May I know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that this for loop has to be closed before running other codes

```
for /f "usebackq" %d in (`dir /ad/b/s "E:\Test2_Backups\"`) do rd "%d"
```

There are ways online to lead to another segment of the codes which is considered a workaround in cmd, but for me, the easiest will be for me to spilt up the codes for 2 scheduled tasks.